# MySQL database convert to PHP arrays

Tags: php, mysql

I want to make a little search engine for zip codes.
I have connected the database. The thing is, I dont know how to let my php code, search in the database to look for hints.

```
<?php
    // Array with zipcodes
    $a[] = "5486EE";



    // get the q parameter from URL
    $q = $_REQUEST["q"];

    $hint = "";

    // lookup all hints from array if $q is different from ""
    if ($q !== "") {
        $q = strtolower($q);
        $len=strlen($q);
        foreach($a as $name) {
            if (stristr($q, substr($name, 0, $len))) {
                if ($hint === "") {
                    $hint = $name;
                } else {
                    $hint .= ", $name";
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Output "no suggestion" if no hint was found or output correct values
    echo $hint === "" ? "" : $hint;
?>
```

I thought it was nice to convert all zipcodes in my database to PHP arrays.
 But I dont know how, if its even possible or not.

Thank you.

(My english is not that good, I'm sorry for that)

Comment: are you asking how to pull data from MySQL and convert that into an array? where is your database code?

Comment: The database is located in mine local server (Xamp), I converted an csv file into a database, wich  database do you need?